# CSS - Apply conditional style to table row

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement where i have to apply conditional style for my table rows but the style never gets applied.

```css
.test1 {
  background-color: '#ffbf00';
}
.test2 {
  background-color: '#92D050';
}
.test3 {
  background-color: ' ';
}
```

```html
<table id="testTable">
  <tr styleClass="test1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the styling will never be applied. something i am missing?

Comment: 'styleClass' Where did you get that from?

Comment: hexa colors are not string... remove your quotes and styleClass doesn't exist.

Comment: What's `styleClass`? Is this an intended custom attribute? Class attributes should just be `class`.

Comment: styleClass is from JSF as far as I know.

Comment: If you *really have to* use `styleClass` as a selector, use it as follows: `tr[styleClass="test1"] {background-color: '#ffbf00';}`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have like 10 mistakes in this HTML code. Please learn HTML and CSS. Here is what you might want to achieve in a correct manner.

```css
.test1 {
  background-color: #ffbf00;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: #92D050;
}
.test3 {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table id="testTable">
  <tr class="test1">
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Do not put quotes on colors. It means class, not styleClass. ' ' is not a valid color value.

Comment: Haha dude, take it easy on OP, we all start somewhere - I shudder to think of the unspeakable tactics I employed back in the day. What do you mean "colon" (:)? Or do you mean "single apostrophe" (')?

Comment: Yep I mean apostrophe, edited. Sorry if you come from a web development background those description languages appear to be very simple I did not want to sound unfriendly ;-)

Comment: This is a great website to improve CSS skills: https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: That was a terrible mistake i have done in my entire life .. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use class for the definition in HTML and don't use quotes around the hex value.

```css
.test1 {
  background-color: #ffbf00;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: #92D050;
}
.test3 {
  background-color: ' ';
}
```

```html
<table id="testTable">
  <tr class="test1">
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

target to `td`

```
.test1 td
    {
        background-color: #ffbf00;
    }
    .test2 td
    {
        background-color: #92D050;
    }
    .test3 td
    {
        background-color: none;
    }
```

Comment: but that class will be applied to only tr?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add class name and **styleClass="test1"** not proper syntax

so update

```
styleClass="test1"
```

to

```
class="test1"
```

and one more thing your style code is not perfect
so also update

```
background-color: '#92D050';
```

to

```
background-color: #92D050;
```

cause this is also syntax error
other code is ok

```css
  .test1 {
        background-color: #ffbf00;
    }
    .test2  {
        background-color: #92D050;
    }
    .test3  {
        background-color: rebeccapurple;
    }
```

```html
<table id="testTable">
    <tr class="test1">
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test2">
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test3">
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```